# Wp_query returning only one post while query through ajax

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I am using ajax with wordpress. But while querying through ajax into function i am getting only one post.

here is my code :

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'order'           => 'DESC',
  );

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
  if($posts->have_posts()){
    while ($posts->have_posts()) {
      $posts->the_post();
        $output = get_the_title();
    }
  }wp_reset_postdata();

  wp_send_json( $output );
```

In console log im getting lastpost title only :(

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the `$output` value in the loop. Declare an empty variable first, and then append each result to it in the loop:

```
  if($posts->have_posts()){
    $output = '';
    while ($posts->have_posts()) {
      $posts->the_post();
        $output .= get_the_title();
    }
  }
```

This will add all the posts to the `$output` variable.